# PHP PDO, SQL if exists update else insert

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im no sql pro and I am having trouble checking if row/record exists with these values then update, else insert these values as new row/record. As of now I am just checking to see if fname exists just to see if its working but its not doing anything. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
   $sql = "IF EXISTS(select fname from contactscms where fname=:fname)
            THEN
            UPDATE contactscms SET contactID, :fname, :lname, :email, :streetaddress, :city, :province, :postalcode, :phone, :yob;
            ELSE
            INSERT INTO contactscms (contactID, fname, lname, email, streetaddress, city, province, postalcode, phone, yob) VALUES (contactID, :fname, :lname, :email, :streetaddress, :city, :province, :postalcode, :phone, :yob)
    ";
    $query = $CONNECTION_STRING->prepare($sql);
   
    $query->execute(array(
        ':fname' => $bigArr[$key][0],
        ':lname' => $bigArr[$key][1],
        ':email' => $bigArr[$key][2],
        ':streetaddress'=> $bigArr[$key][3],
        ':city' => $bigArr[$key][4],
        ':province' => $bigArr[$key][5],
        ':postalcode' => $bigArr[$key][6],
        ':phone' => $bigArr[$key][7],
        ':yob' => $bigArr[$key][8]
    ));
```

Comment: You can use placeholders only once, so use `:fname1` and `:fname2`. If you had [checked for PDO errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) you should have gotten a nice informative error message (or use `try` .... `catch`).

Comment: I did what you mentioned and its not throwing and error/msg and its still not doing anything

Comment: I think there has to be an error, strange that you didn't detect it. Did you make all the placeholders unique? Did you read the manual again and added the `END IF` at the end? Ah, and the next comment might also be relevant.

Comment: You can't use `IF` in that context: it's intended for use as part of a stored procedure. What you want is [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)